# Custom NuGet does not give the all methods if you use it from different path in c#

Tags: c#, nuget

I have successfully created a custom NuGet. It has three methods which return a string. Then I tried to test it in two different ways.

**Method 1**

Added NuGet Tools -> NuGet package manager -> package manager settings -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Sources

Then added a new NuGet (path is selected myproject -> bin -> Release -> test.nupkg), this works properly and can access all three methods.

**Method 2**

I copied `test.nupkg` to the Desktop and then added using above steps.
But it cannot access all the method. (can access only two methods).

When I take the projects from git, there were two methods and I added the third method myself.

Comment: So you've created a NuGet package but you get a different assembly when you access the package from 2 different locations?

Comment: The Release folder is an odd place for a nuget package. You know when you clean the project it will be deleted?

Comment: It's really unclear what steps exactly you took. My guess would be that the project you're testing this on already has the official package installed (the "two methods" version), and present in its packages cache directory. Reinstalling the package will, given the version didn't change, use the version from the cache.

Comment: so where should I put it @Crowcoder

Comment: @Jobs you can put it wherever you want, but you should not want to put it within the bin folder. You could use the local cache, find out where it is on the command line with: `nuget locals all -list`

Answer (score 0):

Nuget packages work the same, no matter where their source is. They don't lose code.

The only logical explanation is that you copied an old one to your desktop or that you chose the old path when you should have chosen your desktop as install location.